# procedure to update the location error PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-5.1

Hello stack overflow community, I have encountered an error while trying to to create procedure to update the location I am new so if i could have some assistance to fix this minor error

```
create or replace PROCEDURE updateLOCATION(
       p_CON_ID IN LDS_CONSULTANT.CONSULTANT_ID@,
       p_CON_NAME IN LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION@)
IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE LDS_CONSULTANT SET LOCATION = p_CON_NAME where CONSULTANT_ID = p_CON_ID;

  COMMIT;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *monkey* at the end of parameters' type declaration and add `%type`, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updatelocation (
  p_con_id     IN lds_consultant.consultant_id%type,
  p_con_name   IN lds_consultant.location%type
)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE lds_consultant
    SET
      location = p_con_name
  WHERE consultant_id = p_con_id;
END;
```

Also, I believe that you should remove the `COMMIT` call and let the caller decide when to commit. As it seems to be Apex-related, there's probably a **submit** button which calls a process which calls that procedure. If that's so, pushing a button will also commit changes you've made.